# Missing property LocalCustomProperties for Microsoft.Graph.TermStore.Term

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

basically we want to use Microsoft Graph to add a term in a term set in SharePoint, but this term is a navigation term. In order to modify the url of the term and choose the navigation Node Type as "Simple Link or Header", with SharePoint Taxonomy API we were filling the property LocalCustomProperties, but this property is no available from Microsoft Graph.

Does it mean that this is not supported from Microsoft Graph?

Is there another way to get/update this without using LocalCustomProperties property?

Thanks,
Roberto

I was trying to create a Microsoft.Graph.TermStore.Term with the Properties property but it's not the same as the LocalCustomProperties, so I cannot provisiong a navigation term with "Simple Link or Header".

I used Graph Explorer to see what properties are returned and the properties related to the navigation are not coming.